# ijParcelFileDescriptor is always null in java APIs

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

Inside onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj), I am able to access xyz but not ij data. Why is it always null ? or is it just matter of time before the same is exposed to java layer ?

```
if (xyzIj.ijParcelFileDescriptor != null) {
    try {
        final byte[] ijBuffer
            = new byte[xyzIj.ijRows * xyzIj.ijCols * 4];
        FileInputStream ijFileStream 
            = new FileInputStream(xyzIj.ijParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

        ijFileStream.read(ijBuffer);
        ijFileStream.close();

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also nulled out when using the C API. The SDK [release notes history](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/release-notes) shows that this feature is not available (under Known Issues of the Archimedes release):

> The IJ buffer of the XYZij struct is under development and not yet
>   populated via the API.

I think we can assume that if this had changed it would have been stated in subsequent release notes. It certainly would be nice if the documentation mentioned it, as it does for the also unimplemented [`TangoXYZij::color_image`](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/struct_tango_x_y_zij#a4abd9e848f8a19bd000bbb3b637e4179).

The [Known Issues](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/known-issues) page also documents the lack of support for this feature.